# IBM - COS - SDK IAM token

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am trying to access my COS service using python.Referring IBM's Documentation  was able to write the following code snippet

```
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config

api_key = 'key'
service_instance_id = 'resource-service-id'
auth_endpoint = 'http://iam.bluemix.net/'
service_endpoint = 'endpoint'
s3 = ibm_boto3.resource('s3',
                  ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
                  ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
                  ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
                  config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                  endpoint_url=service_endpoint)
s3.Bucket('bucket name').download_file('object name','location where the object must be saved')
```

Is this correct ? Also while trying to execute the above code the compiler is not able to retrieve the authentication token from auth_endpoint. Am i missing something?

Please to help

Thanks in advance!

I am including the output for your reference...

```
  ibm_botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError: Error when retrieving credentials from https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token: Retrieval of tokens from server failed
```

And I am using python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As instructed in README, the auth_endpoint should have /oidc/token at the end, for example, 'http://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token'.

```
auth_endpoint = 'https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token'
```

Answer (score 0):

The auth_endpoint should be https

See the example here
https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python

Answer (score 0):

## To Connect with ibm cloud storage account we need api_key, service_instace_id,auth_endpoint and service_endpoint.

```
import ibm_boto3    
from ibm_botocore.client import Config       
api_key = '......' # u can find api_key in service credentials in ibm cloud account    
service_instance_id = '.....' u can find service_instance_id in service credentials in ibm cloud account      
auth_endpoint = 'https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token'    
service_endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'


cos = ibm_boto3.resource('s3',
ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
endpoint_url=service_endpoint)
```

## to create a bucket

```
    new_bucket = 'abcd1234'
    def create_bucket():
        cos.create_bucket(Bucket=new_bucket)
    return "Bucket created sucessfully"
```

create_bucket()

## to list Buckets in cloud

```
def get_buckets():
    print("Retrieving list of buckets")
try:
    buckets = cos.buckets.all()
    for bucket in buckets:
        print("Bucket Name: {0}".format(bucket.name))
except ClientError as be:
    print("CLIENT ERROR: {0}\n".format(be))
except Exception as e:
    print("Unable to retrieve list buckets: {0}".format(e))
```

get_buckets()